# Validate textbox depending on combo box value in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, validation, combobox, textbox

I am sorry if this seems to be simple,but I really can't find this. I want to validate a text box depending on a combo box selection. 
combo box has 3 values as NIC, SSN and Passport. I want to validate text box depending on this selection.
If NIC is selected 9 Digits and V like wise, please help

thank you

....code provided...

```
Private Function validatenic() 
    If cmdCustProfileID.Text = "NIC" Then 
        txtBoxID.TextMaskFormat = "000000000v" 
    End If 
    Return True 
End Function
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Anyway...you can't validate a Passport number since Passport numbers vary across countries and there is no worldwide pattern.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried already. Also specify if this is a WinForm or WebForm app. If WebForm do you wish to validate client side as well as server side or server side only.

Comment: This is what i tried doing, and this is win form Private Function validatenic()
        If cmdCustProfileID.Text = "NIC" Then
            txtBoxID.TextMaskFormat = "000000000v"
        End If
        Return True
    End Function

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be changing the mask when you call the validate function but the mask should be changed when the drop down list is changes. You should use the SelectedIndexChanged event of the DropDownList something like this....

```
Protected Sub ddlIdType_SIC () Handles ddlIdType.SelectedIndexChanged

    Select Case ddlIdType.Value

        Case "NIC"
            textboxID.TextMaskFormat = "00000000v"

        Case "Passport"
            textboxID.TextMaskFormat = "00000000"  'change to whatever your passport mask is

        Case "SSN"
            textboxID.TextMaskFormat = "00000000"  'change to whatever your SSN mask is

     End Select

 End Sub
```